# React -> State Management

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner with React. I want to build an application similar to the page (howmuchtomakeanapp.com). That means that for every choice on a route a user does, a price will be added to the total, but when going back with the back button the price will return to the previous one. I know it is state management but I actually have no clue how to do it even after reading the whole react docs.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to modify values based on the page the user is on?

Comment: Which back button are you referring? Back button on your application or Previous Page on the browser?

Comment: @jules Sorry I did not specify, I mean a prev button on my app.

Comment: @Alex Ironside I know it may be confusing, I want to create something similar to the page I linked above, what I mwan is : User selects out 1 out of 3 options, price added to the state, redirected to the next page. On the next page choses again 1 out of 3 or whatever options, and price increases, but if he clicks another option by mistake, with a back button he can go back 1 step to the previous price.

Comment: You could learn it from [React State Management Libraries](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React state is stored locally within a component. When it needs to be shared with other components, it is passed through props. In practice, this means that the component that needs access to a changeable value will keep that value in its state and if it can be changed by subcomponents a callback must be passed to handle the change.

To learn more about components and props, this is the link to the React documentation itself: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

I recommend you take a look at Redux (https://redux.js.org/), that is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I assume you keep your price as a number and add to it the more steps you go further?

I dont think you need to do anything special besides:

My approach would be to keep an array with all the prices, that way you can always remove the last when you click on the prev button. Add one price everytime you select one and navigate to the next route. To display the total you just add the array together:

```
const prices = [3.5,5,10,5.76,23];
const total = prices.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
```

Does that help?